# Unix bash: getting correct number of rows in excel file

Tags: bash, unix, spreadsheet, xlsx

Is there a proper way to find the count of number of rows in xlsx file in unix? Let's assume that it is only 1 sheet per excel file.

`wc -l` is not working here as it gives the count of lines of encoded file, not the number of actual rows.

I found a perl way to do it with [spreadsheet module](https://metacpan.org/release/DMOW/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/view/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) .
Or by converting Excel file to CSV and then counting rows

But is a simple way, without installing additional modules?

Comment: No.  The Exel file format is not "plain text enough" to read it without a library.  Just about any programming language will have a library, but you'll have to install it before having a reasonable time working with exel documents.

Comment: @erik258, where is your sense of adventure!?

Answer (score 1):

This question is funky and I like it!

Any of the newer-style office files that end in "x" like .xls***x*** and .doc***x*** are actually zipped folders full of lots of .xml and other content. If you want to look at the xml for one of the sheets from Unix, you just need to unzip it and then start poking around.

To dig in further, I grabbed a spreadsheet off of my home server using a linux machine that has no office package and validated what I just suggested above.

```bash
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads$ ls
'Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx'
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads$ file 'Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx' 
Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx: Microsoft Excel 2007+
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads$ unzip 'Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx' 
Archive:  Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml     
  inflating: _rels/.rels             
  inflating: xl/workbook.xml         
  inflating: xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels  
  inflating: xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml  
  inflating: xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml  
  inflating: xl/theme/theme1.xml     
  inflating: xl/styles.xml           
  inflating: xl/sharedStrings.xml    
  inflating: xl/drawings/drawing1.xml  
  inflating: xl/charts/chart1.xml    
  inflating: xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels  
  inflating: xl/drawings/_rels/drawing1.xml.rels  
  inflating: xl/calcChain.xml        
  inflating: docProps/core.xml       
  inflating: docProps/app.xml        
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads$ ls
'[Content_Types].xml'   docProps  'Monte Carlo Simulation.xlsx'   _rels   xl
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads$ cd xl
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl$ ls
calcChain.xml  charts  drawings  _rels  sharedStrings.xml  styles.xml  theme  workbook.xml  worksheets
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl$ vim workbook.xml 
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl$ cd worksheets/
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl/worksheets$ ls
_rels  sheet1.xml  sheet2.xml
```

In the xl/worksheets/ folder I found xml documents for each worksheet, which contained xml that isn't really formatted (all in a single line). I formatted this using the widely available xmllint tool and then read through it a bit. In it, I found a "dimension" field right near the front as well as individual formatting fields for each row

```bash
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl/worksheets$ xmllint --format sheet1.xml | grep dimension
  <dimension ref="A1:G60"/>
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl/worksheets$ xmllint --format sheet1.xml | grep 60
  <dimension ref="A1:G60"/>
        <v>0.94903607351434327</v>
        <v>60</v>
        <v>1.029702686080076</v>
        <v>460</v>
    <row r="60" spans="1:7" ht="13.2" thickBot="1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
```

so you could probably do something like this to figure out what the lowest row is in what I'm assuming is the range that actually has data

```bash
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl/worksheets$ xmllint --format sheet1.xml | grep dimension | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
60
scott@chromebook-edgar:~/Downloads/xl/worksheets$ xmllint --format sheet2.xml | grep dimension | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
204
```